# How to use Swift's higher order functions for parsing dynamic dictionary data in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, swift4, higher-order-functions

I am trying to parse the following json and want to retrieve the "key" of a dictionary whose value matches with the given value.

```
{ "OuterArrayHolder" : 
  [
    { 
      "dictDynamicKey" : ["dynamicValue1", "dynamicValue2", "dynamicValue3"]
    },
    { 
      "dictAnotherDynamicKey" : ["dynamicValue4", "dynamicValue5", "dynamicValue6"]
    },
  ]
}
```

[Note: Here in above json, all the keys and values are dynamic except "OuterArrayHolder".]

I have implemented it in a non-Swifty way and currently **getting the expected output**, but I am not getting how to accomplish the same behaviour using **swift's higher-order functions**.

> Input : "dynamicValue2"
>
> Expected output : "dictDynamicKey"

Current solution:

```
let inputValue = "dynamicValue2"

if !outerArrayHolder.isEmpty {
   for dynamicDict in outerArrayHolder {
      for (key, value) in dynamicDict {
        if value.empty || !value.contains(inputValue) {
          continue
        } else {
           //here if inputValue matches in contianed array (value is array in dictionary) then I want to use its "repective key" for further businisess logic.
        }
      }
   }
}
```

I want to reduce these two for loops and want to use higher-order functions to achieve the exact behavior, Any help in this regard is really appreciated.

Comment: The higher-order function version of `for...in` is `forEach`. Apart from that it's hard to see what else you expect. I'm not sure I see what you think is "non-Swifty" about this. You are doing some stuff that is unnecessary; for example, `if !outerArrayHolder.isEmpty` is pointless, because if it _is_ empty the `for...in` loop will not execute anyway. And saying `if condition...continue...else...otherthing` is silly, because you might as well say `if !condition otherthing`. But that has nothing to do with "higher-order" anything; it's just that you're being unnecessarily verbose.

Comment: @matt so apart from unnecessary stuff, could you please suggest is there any other way to retrieve the dynamicKey using higher-order functions and avoiding for-in/forEach.

Comment: `forEach` _is_ a higher-order function. Unclear what you imagine a "higher-order function" is or would do for you that's different from what you're doing. A loop is a loop, no matter how expressed.

Comment: How many times are you doing this? Because doing a linear search over an array of dictionaries, linearly searching over each one's entries, linear searching over each one's array of values would be *really* slow for big datasets or frequent accesses.

Comment: @matt I mean using the "filter" function. Something like outerArrayHolder.filter {($0...some code goes here.......)}

Comment: But `filter` is a loop so it's no different (in terms of complexity) from what you're doing. In fact, it is _less_ efficient than what you're doing because it loops through everything, whereas you can easily stop as soon as you get the answer.

Comment: Those who have downvoted, kindly take an effort to justify or add your comments why it's downvoted which would help me to refine my question/query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can we convert your algorithm to a functional style? Yes. Is it a good idea? Probably not in this case. But here's how.

You didn't give any type information, so I'll use this type:

```
let outerArrayHolder: [[String: Any]] = [
    [
        "dictDynamicKey": ["dynamicValue1", "dynamicValue2", "dynamicValue3"]
    ],
    [
        "dictAnotherDynamicKey" : ["dynamicValue4", "dynamicValue5", "dynamicValue6"]
    ],
]
```

And you want to find the key corresponding to the array that contains `inputValue`:

```
let inputValue = "dynamicValue2"
```

The functional strategy is to map each dictionary in `outerArrayHolder` to its first key that has a matching value. If a dictionary has no such key, the dictionary is mapped to nil. Then we throw away the nils and take the first remaining value.

We can do it with `filter`, as requested:

```
let key = outerArrayHolder.lazy
    .compactMap {
        $0.lazy
            .filter { ($0.value as? [String])?.contains(inputValue) ?? false }
            .map { $0.key }
            .first }
    .first
```

But we can save a `lazy` and a `first` using `first(where:)`:

```
let key = outerArrayHolder.lazy
    .compactMap({
        $0
            .first(where: { ($0.value as? [String])?.contains(inputValue) ?? false })
            .map { $0.key }
    }).first
```

Comment: Thanks rob, I will give it a try. Could you please elaborate whats the purpose of "outerArrayHolder.lazy" here, can't we just use "outerArrayHolder.compactMap", please suggest.

Comment: If you use `outerArrayHolder.compactMap`, then you'll construct an array of all matching keys, and then keep only the first. If you use `lazy`, it finds the keys on demand. Since `first` only demands the first match, you don't spend time and memory finding all matching keys.

Comment: Thank you rob, this is what I was looking for. I will explore more on it and revert in case of any query, so that in case if anyone else having same query, your solution would help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what this has to do with higher-order functions. If the outer key is known, I would simply write

```
// just building your structure
let d1 = ["dictDynamicKey" : ["dynamicValue1", "dynamicValue2", "dynamicValue3"]]
let d2 = ["dictAnotherDynamicKey" : ["dynamicValue4", "dynamicValue5", "dynamicValue6"]]
let d = ["OuterArrayHolder" : [d1, d2]]

// this is the actual code:

func find(_ target:String) -> String? {
    for dict in d["OuterArrayHolder"]! {
        for (k,v) in dict {
            if v.contains(target) {return k}
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

That's just what you're doing, only it's clean.

Comment: Yes, I agree with your solution and point, but what I am trying to do is to remove the outer for loop (possibly outer and inner loop as well) and replace it with "filter", this would also help me in understanding how to use "filter" in such kind of data.

Comment: @iLearner `filter` isn't the right tool for the job. The result of `filter` is `[T]` (multiple `T`s), but you're only looking for a single value. Also, `filter` always goes through all elements of the target sequence, which is not what you want, either. Besides, using `filter` "doesn't get rid of the loop", it just hides it. Internally `filter` is using a for-loop through and through.

Comment: @iLearner you don't get to say "I will accept only an answer that works in way x". Whether "way x" will actually work, or whether it is the "best" way, is exactly what you don't know. That is why you have a question. If you knew whether you could appropriately impose that sort of condition you'd already know the answer to the question.

Comment: It's not about accepting the answer, your comments are really helpful, but what I was asking is, is there any better way of the same things which am currently doing by iteration with two loops.

Comment: @iLearner it's great that you are asking that, but now you need to listen for the answer. First, "better" is a matter of opinion. Better _how_? By what criteria or measure? Faster? Prettier? Swiftier? I showed you a prettier, Swiftier version. Second, the "higher-order" functions like `map` and `filter` _are_ loops; it makes no difference whether _you_ loop or the function loops for you, it's the same loop. And the dance required for early exit with a higher-order function is arguably _uglier_ and less comprehensible. So it is unclear what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

There's no higher order function that does precisely what you're looking for. The closest is `first(where:)`, but the problem is that the result is just `Bool`, and you don't have a way to cleanly fish out data related to the found case.

You could write something like:

```
extension Sequence {
    func findFirst<T>(where predicate: (Element) throws -> T?) rethrows -> T? {
        for element in self {
            if let result = try predicate(element) {
                return result
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

and then use it like:

```
let dictionaries = [
    [ 
        "dictDynamicKey" : ["dynamicValue1", "dynamicValue2", "dynamicValue3"]
    ],
    [ 
        "dictAnotherDynamicKey" : ["dynamicValue4", "dynamicValue5", "dynamicValue6"]
    ],
]

let desiredValue = "dynamicValue2"

extension Sequence {
    func findFirst<T>(where predicate: (Element) throws -> T?) rethrows -> T? {
        for element in self {
            if let result = try predicate(element) {
                return result
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}

let result = dictionaries.findFirst(where: { dict in
    dict.findFirst(where: { key, values in
        values.contains(desiredValue) ? key : nil
    })
})

print(result as Any) // => Optional("dictDynamicKey")
```

But it's probably more complexity than it's probably worth. I would recommend Matt's solution.

## Scaled solution

You haven't clarified on this, but I suspect that you probably need to do this a bunch of times. In that case, linear searching through this gets really slow. By searching for keys by their values, you're not taking advantage of the key benefit of dictionaries: constant-time access to a value by its key. Your code is:

1. Linear-searching through the array of dictionaries, introduces an `O(dictionaries.count)` factor
2. For each dict in the array in #1, linear-searching through the key/value pairs, which introduces a `O(dict.count)` factor
3. For each key/value pair in the dict in #2, linear-searching through array of values, which introduces a `O(valueArray.count)` factor.

The total time complexity multiplies up to `O(dictionaries.count * averageDict.count * averageValueArray.count)`, which gets really slow really quick.

Instead, you can spend some compute cost up-front, to create a new data structure that is better able to service the kinds of queries you want to run on it. In this case, you can "invert" a dictionary.

```
extension Dictionary {
    func inverted<T>() -> [T: Key] where Dictionary.Value == [T] {
        let invertedKeyValuePairs = self
            .lazy
            .flatMap { oldKey, oldValues in
                oldValues.map { oldValue in (key: oldValue, value: oldKey) as (T, Key) }
            }

        return Dictionary<T, Key>(uniqueKeysWithValues: invertedKeyValuePairs) 
    }
}

// Example usage:
let valuesByKeys = [
"a": [1, 2, 3],
"b": [4, 5, 6]
]

let keysPerValue = valuesByKeys.inverted()

keysPerValue.forEach { key, value in print("key: \(key), value: \(value)") }
// Which results in:
// key: 3, value: a
// key: 4, value: b
// key: 5, value: b
// key: 1, value: a
// key: 6, value: b
// key: 2, value: a
```

Given such an `inverted` implementation, you can invert each dict of your input set, and merge them all together:

```
let invertedDictionary = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: dictionaries.flatMap { $0.inverted() })
invertedDictionary.forEach { key, value in print("key: \(key), value: \(value)") }
// Result: 
key: dynamicValue6, value: dictAnotherDynamicKey
key: dynamicValue1, value: dictDynamicKey
key: dynamicValue2, value: dictDynamicKey
key: dynamicValue3, value: dictDynamicKey
key: dynamicValue4, value: dictAnotherDynamicKey
key: dynamicValue5, value: dictAnotherDynamicKey
```

You can store and share this dictionary, which can give constant time (`O(1)`) access to the key that was associated with any desired value:

```
print(invertedDictionary[desiredValue] as Any) // => Optional("dictDynamicKey")
```